# Another test to determine which function is bigger?

Tags: derivatives, inequality

Assuming that $f(x) \geq g(x)$ , what are the necessary and sufficient conditions about $f(x),g(x),f'(x),g'(x)$ to conclude that also $f'(x) \geq g'(x)$ ?!

Comment: Do we have $f(x)\ge g(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$ and is $f(x)-g(x)$ defined everywhere ?

Comment: $f(x) \geq g(x)$ starting from a number not necessary 0 . also $f(x)-g(x)$ need not to be defined everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference between the two functions must increase (not strictly) i.e. $(f-g)(x)$ must be a non decreasing function. I think it's a necessary and sufficient condition (of course under continuity and differentiation conditions).